# Difference in LINQ query results in .NET 3.5 and 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I executed the following code with C# 3.5 and 4.0. The results are entirely different.

```
    static void Main()
    {       
        int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
        List<IEnumerable<int>> results = new List<IEnumerable<int>>();

        foreach (var num in numbers)
        {
            results.Add(numbers.Where(item => item > num));
        }

        foreach (var r in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", r.Count());
        }        
    }
```

With Microsoft (R) Visual C# 2008 Compiler version 3.5.30729.5420 the output is `0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`.

But with Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.0.30319.17929 the output is `9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0`.

I have a faint idea that this is because of deferred execution or lazy evaluation but haven't clearly understood how it is responsible for different outputs here.

**Correction:** Sorry it was .NET 3.5 and 4.5 and also added compiler versions
**Please explain.**

Comment: I get the same output in 3.5 and 4.0, { 9 8 7 ... } are you sure you're not doing something different?

Comment: It is giving me same results ....

Comment: I believe this change happened with 4.5, not 4.0.

Comment: @JoeEnos It has nothing to do with the version of .NET, it is related to the version of C# being used.

Comment: @Servy Gotcha, thanks. Hard to keep those distinctions clear sometimes.

Comment: @JoeEnos I made a mistake with .NET version but in the question I mentioned the version of compiler right

Comment: @mssrivatsa No you didn't.  It was changed in C# 5.0, not 4.0.  There also is no such thing as C# 3.5.

Comment: @Servy No I had the different output with C# 4.0 compiler
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.0.30319.17929

Comment: @mssrivatsa Then you are mistaken.  It was changed in C# 5.0.  The 4.0 compiler wouldn't produce that result.

Comment: @Servy: Though there is no *language* C# 3.5, there is a *compiler release* that is version 3.5.  The compiler version numbers match the version of the framework they shipped with, not the language they analyze. Yes, this is unnecessarily confusing, and I heartily wish that my former colleagues would get their versioning story straight. This is a perennial problem across Microsoft.

Comment: @Servy Yes it did. Here is the screenshot http://jmp.sh/b/VQQmAsiUIoEy9jByahPY

Comment: @mssrivatsa Well, perhaps Eric can clarify the versioning system further.  You're compiling against the C# 5.0 language specs.  Apparently the version of the C# compiler that you are using is capable of compiling against the C# 5.0 language.  This is a feature that has always had a lot of attention here, because people post this exacted problem several times a day back when most new C# programmers were using C# 3-4.

Comment: @Servy I agree with you but i was talking in terms of compiler and you were in terms of language versions

Answer (score 7):

Since c# 5, the loop variable in `foreach` is compiled such that it exists within the loop scope rather than outside it.

This means that when you close over the loop variable, you get different results.

[Here's what Eric Lippert](http://ericlippert.com/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful-part-one/) had to say about the original problem.

Comment: It's since C# 5.0, not .NET 4.0.

Comment: This doesn't answers the question. OP asks in c# 4.0. but your 're taking about c# 5.0

Comment: OP asks about .net4. This is the only possibility for the observed results.

Comment: For compatibility use var t = num; in foreach loop.

Comment: Much better. earlier question had c#4.0. now edited

Comment: @Habib I know that very well so that am confused how OP got that result and with this answer too. Now am clear. Confusion is question was wrong.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Installing 4.5 changes the behavior of .NET 4.0 due to it updating the BCL without changing the version numbers.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Yes, IIRC that will change the behavior of .net 3.5 too.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel just tested it, you are correct.

Answer (score 6):

You have accessed a variable inside a closure, therefore the results will differ on different versions of the compiler.

In C# 5.0, the variable is redefined in each iteration of the loop, whereas in previous C# versions it was only defined once.

For more info, see Eric Lippert's great [blog post](http://ericlippert.com/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful-part-one/)

More notably, the opening paragraph:

> UPDATE: We are taking the breaking change. In C# 5, the loop variable of a foreach will be logically inside the loop, and therefore closures will close over a fresh copy of the variable each time. The "for" loop will not be changed. We return you now to our original article.

Comment: The scope of the variable has *nothing* to do with the version of .NET.  It has everything to do with the version of C#.  It was changed in C# 5.0.

Comment: Have you read eric's blog `We are taking the breaking change. In C# 5`

Comment: @Servy Yeah I clarified that, thanks.

Comment: Yes, in VS2012 compiling with .NET 3.5, it's work perfectly.

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria That's because you're using the C# 5.0 compiler.  The version of .NET used is irrelevant.

Comment: @Servy Exactly what I wanted to point out.